# how to get unique phone number by using hashmap in android

Tags: android-studio

I have created an database server using images and phone numbers in columns.I have given a specific single phone number by which all images are stored using that single number in database server. Now I changed the phone number in server directly with different different numbers . Now I want to display the image with phone number . So how can I write the code in android for displaying images as well phone number( number in HashMap).

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("asd", response);


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("documents"));


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String docId = jsonObject1.getString("docId");
                    String docImage = jsonObject1.getString("docImage");
                    String uid = jsonObject1.getString("uid");

                    arrayList.add(docImage);
                    // arrayList.add(uid);

                }

                CustomSwipeAdapter customSwipeAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(ImagesSlidingActivity.this, arrayList);

                viewPager.setAdapter(customSwipeAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.d("asd", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.d("asd", "error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);`
```

Comment: create a Pair<PhoneNumber, List<Images>>.
And if you have implemented anything regarding this than include it in the question so everyone can know how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume that your `arrayList` is type of String. like

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Change it to

```
List<Pair<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

So your code will be something like following.

```
List<Pair<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("asd", response);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("documents"));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String docId = jsonObject1.getString("docId");
                String docImage = jsonObject1.getString("docImage");
                String uid = jsonObject1.getString("uid");
                Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<>(uid, docImage);
                arrayList.add(pair);
            }

            CustomSwipeAdapter customSwipeAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(ImagesSlidingActivity.this, arrayList);

            viewPager.setAdapter(customSwipeAdapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.d("asd", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Log.d("asd", "error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Please note that by changing this you need to change the type of arraylist in your **`CustomSwipeAdapter`**. 
And from the pair object you can get id using **`pair.first`** and image using **`pair.second`**

Happy Coding.. :)